# Java Почему метод не определен?

Tags: java, классы, методы

Вопрос про метод `static void data` в классе `Flat_town`

```
class Room{
  double area;
  public Room(double area){
  this.area=area;
  }
}

 class Flat extends Room{
  int floor;
  double kitchenar;
  public Flat(double area,int floor,double kitchenar){
  super(area);
  this.floor=floor;
  this.kitchenar=kitchenar;
  }
}
 class Flat_town extends Flat{
  String town;
  public Flat_town(double area,int floor,double kitchenar, String town){
  super(area, floor, kitchenar);
  this.town=town;
  }
  static void data(String town,int floor,double area, double kitchenar){
  System.out.println(" Город "+ town + " Этаж " + floor + " Площадь комнаты "+ area + " Площадь кухни "+ kitchenar);
  }
}
```

(Здесь пропуск блока с вводом и прочим)
Через System.out.println всё работает.
Но вызов метода не работает . Выдает следующее : `The method data(String, int, double, double) is undefined for the type Main`

Подскажите, что я делаю не так, пожалуйста.

```
    Flat_town flat_town1 = new Flat_town(number,number1,number2,s);
    data(s,number1,number,number2);
    System.out.println(" Город "+ flat_town1.town + " Этаж " + flat_town1.floor + " Площадь комнаты "+ flat_town1.area + " Площадь кухни "+ flat_town1.kitchenar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка расшифровывается следующим образом: метод `data` не определён в классе `Main`

А определён он в классе `Flat_town`

Поскольку метод статический, то для его вызова не в классе `Flat_town` (например в методах класса `Main`) нужно указывать `Flat_town` - имя класса где он определён, вот так:

```
Flat_town.data(s,number1,number,number2);
```